# question about error var newCell = random(chooseCell(1)); in this stroke I have error: chooseCell is not defined

Tags: javascript, object, canvas

So I wrote this code. Its wrong I guess. Can you please help me. I'll be very gratefull. Is there any other errors too?

var newCell = random(chooseCell(1)); in this stroke I have error: chooseCell is not defined

```
     class GrassEater{
            constructor(x,y,index){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.index = index;
                this.energy = 5;
                this.directions = [];}
         getNewCoordinates(){
           this.directions = [
        [this.x - 1, this.y - 1],
            [this.x    , this.y - 1],
            [this.x + 1, this.y - 1],
                [this.x - 1, this.y    ],
                [this.x + 1, this.y    ],
                [this.x - 1, this.y + 1],
                [this.x    , this.y + 1],
                [this.x + 1, this.y + 1]];}
    chooseCell(character) {this.getNewCoordinates();
                var found = [];
                for (var i in this.directions) {
                    var x = this.directions[i][0];
                    var y = this.directions[i][1];
                    if (x >= 0 && x < matrix[0].length && y >= 0 && y <matrix.length) { if (matrix[y][x] == character) {
                            found.push(this.directions[i]); } }}
                return found;}
         move() {var newCell = random(this.chooseCell(0));
         if (newCell) {var newX = newCell[0];
                    var newY = newCell[1];
                     matrix[this.y][this.x] = 0;
                    matrix[newY][newX] = this.index;
                    this.y = newY;
                    this.x = newX;
                    this.energy--;}}
 mul() { var newCell = random(this.chooseCell(0));
                     if (this.energy >= 8 && newCell) {
                   var  animalArr = new GrassEater(newCell[0], newCell[1], this.index);
                    grassEaterArr.push(animalArr); 
                    matrix[newCell[1]][newCell[0]] = 2;
                    this.energy = 5; }}
        eat(){var newCell = random(chooseCell(1));
  if(newCell) { var newX = newCell[0];
                    var newY = newCell[1];
                     matrix[this.x][this.y]= 0;
                     matrix[newY][newX]= this.index;
                        this.energy--;}
                         this.y= newY;
                      this.x= newX;
                         this.energy += 3 }}
```

Comment: Missed `this`, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of these is not like the others:

```
      var newCell = random(this.chooseCell(0));
```

```
      var newCell = random(this.chooseCell(0));
```

```
      var newCell = random(chooseCell(1));
```

`this` is missing.